# Can I use the Python SHAP package to get the marginal contribution to RSquared for each feature?

Tags: python, data-science

I am trying to reproduce the [example](http://www.real-statistics.com/multiple-regression/shapley-owen-decomposition/) and I was wondering if there is a way to do this with the Python Shap package. I'm not sure how to use the `LinearExplainer()` to get marginal contribution to RSquared.

What I have tried so far:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import shap
shap.initjs()

X = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x1','x2','x3'], data=[[7,3,6],[9,4,8],[12,5,9],[10,8,12],[20,9,23]])
Y = pd.Series(data=[23,45,68,59,89],name='y')

model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, Y)

explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(model, X)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)
```

The output for `shap_values` is:

```
array([[-40.0032057 , -23.7588602 ,  33.24345503],
   [-22.61050757, -15.27355298,  21.37079252],
   [  3.47853963,  -6.78824577,  15.43446126],
   [-13.9141585 ,  18.66767587,  -2.3745325 ],
   [ 73.04933215,  27.15298308, -67.67417631]])
```

Can someone also please help me understand/interpret this output?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are already familiar with the theoretical aspects of how SHAPely values work. I found [this](https://medium.com/@gabrieltseng/interpreting-complex-models-with-shap-values-1c187db6ec83) and [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/explain-your-model-with-the-shap-values-bc36aac4de3d) link helpful for that purpose.

Coming to the output:

```
array([[-40.0032057 , -23.7588602 ,  33.24345503],
   [-22.61050757, -15.27355298,  21.37079252],
   [  3.47853963,  -6.78824577,  15.43446126],
   [-13.9141585 ,  18.66767587,  -2.3745325 ],
   [ 73.04933215,  27.15298308, -67.67417631]])
```

In order to interpret it correctly, let me first generate the predictions using your model as:

```
predictions = model.predict(X)
print (predictions)

>>>
[26.28138914 40.28673197 68.92475512 59.17898486 89.32813891]
```

We have 3 features in the data `x1,x2,x3`. For each data point, we get a set of 3 shapely values. These values indicate how each of the 3 features influences the prediction linearly.
Now consider the first prediction value i.e 26.28. The corresponding SHApely values are: 
`[-40.0032057 , -23.7588602 ,  33.24345503]`

These values indicate how much influence x1 makes to the prediction (-40.003), how much influence x2 makes (-23.758) and x3 (33.243). So we can conclude that x1 and x2 negatively impact the prediction, x3 impacts positively.

To further verify this, get the expected value as:

```
print (explainer.expected_value)
>>> 56.8
```

This expected value is nothing but the mean of the predictions

```
print (np.mean(predictions))
>>> 56.8
```

This indicates that without knowing values of x1,x2,x3 we would have guessed 56.8
The SHAPely values `[-40.0032057 , -23.7588602 ,  33.24345503]` push this guess as:
`56.8 + (-40.0032057) + (-23.7588602) + 33.24345503 = 26.28138914`, which is our final prediction. Thus, to re-iterate the SHAPely values represent **how much each of the features linearly influence the prediction away from the mean(guess)**

You can further verify by:

```
print (shap_values.sum(1) + explainer.expected_value)
>>> [26.28138914 40.28673197 68.92475512 59.17898486 89.32813891]
```

Here I am taking the shap values for each row and adding it to the mean, which results in the prediction for that row. This is the same as our predictions. I hope this helped you get an intuitive understanding on how to interpret the SHAPely values

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This is what I understood too but you've made it MUCH clearer! Any idea if it is possible to get the marginal contributions to R-squared using the `shap` package?

Comment: Thanks @mdinaker.. I am not really sure of the correct way to get the marginal contributions to R-squared. One possible approach is:
 
Consider x1. Make the SHAP values corresponding to x1 zero and get the new predictions. Compute R^2 for this new set of predictions and compare with the previous R^2. This will give you the marginal contribution of x1 to R^2. Next,  repeat the same for x2 and x3